# How to zip only certain extension's files in php? (.pdf, .mp3 and .zip)

Tags: php

I've been trying to zip only .pdf, .mp3 & .zip files in a directory but it zip all of the directories and files. I only want the files with the above extension.

If that can't be happen then I want to exclude some of the files like I want to exclude index.php, foo.html, style.css & script.js.

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        $exclude = array('themes', 'style.css');

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            if (!in_array($file, $exclude)) {

                $file = realpath($file);

                if (is_dir($file) === true)
                {
                    $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                }
                else if (is_file($file) === true)
                {
                    $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

Please help me out, thanks!

Comment: Check the file extension : `if (in_array($file, array('pdf', 'mp3'))` and ignore other.

Comment: You can take a look of how it's done here - https://gist.github.com/jonataswalker/3c0c6b26eabb2e36bc90

Comment: @Debflav I tried your code but it didn't excluded any file. Can u show me the full code? Ty.

Answer (score 1):

List all the extension you would like to exclude/include into a variable.
Then check each flies extension and skip if they are into above list. Can be done using in_array as shown above by 'Debflav'.

Please use the below function to get file extension:

```
/**
 * Get file extension type if we provide the filename. 
 * @param string $filename eg. 'filename.jpg'
 * 
 * @return string Extension only eg. "jpg", 'gif'
 */
function _get_file_extension($filename=null)
{
    $e = explode('.', $filename);

    $extension = (count($e) > 0 ) ? $e[ ( count($e) - 1) ] : null;

    return strtolower($extension);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment you can only process files with extensions mp3, pdf[...] Since you used `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` I'll do the following :

```
if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $allowedExtensions = array('mp3', 'pdf');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
    {
        if (in_array($file->getExtension(), $allowExtensions)
        {
            // Your own logic
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, DirectoryIterator is available since PHP 5 but `getExtension()` is available since PHP 5.3.6. If you are using PHP < 5.3.6 you can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: Nope. This code also didn't helped me out. It downloads all of the files. I used both getExtension and pathinfo function. Lemme know if you've anything else. Ty.

Comment: The problem cannot come from my sample of code... I watch again your code, you can can use functions from the DirectoryIterator class (getFileName()) instead of doing something complicate with realpath().